# 2 Counts Statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, data-science

I am trying to see the number of products sold to different companies by month and year.

For example:

I have a dataset where I have a long list of products. I would like to see two different columns where the first column shows a count of all those products and a second column that shows the company that was sold to by month and year

That is my query:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date) AS Month, COUNT(*), company
FROM database.products
WHERE     YEAR(date) = '2022'
GROUP BY  MONTH(date)
WITH ROLLUP);
```

**Expected Result**:

| Year | Month | Products | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | January | 654 | walmart |
| 2022 | January | 895 | Winco |
| 2022 | February | 562 | Ross |
| 2022 | February | 456 | Best Buy |

Answer (score 1):

Just add the rest of the fields...?

```sql
SELECT YEAR(date) AS Year, MONTHNAME(date) AS Month, COUNT(*), company
FROM database.products
WHERE YEAR(date) = '2022'
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), company
WITH ROLLUP
```